# Reverse a doubly linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, reverse, doubly-linked-list

Here's my simple linked list program that creates a doubly linked list, and it works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node {
  int data;
  node *next;
  node *prev;
}node;

void printList(node *temp);

int main()
{
    node *head;
    head = new node;
    head->prev = NULL;
    node *next = head;
    node *prev = head;
    node *temp = head;
    node *current = head;

    //creates 100 nodes, last one points to next
    for(int x = 0; x<100; x++)
    {
    temp->data = x;
    current = temp;
    temp = new node;
    current->next = temp;
    temp->prev = current;
    temp->next = NULL;
    }
    //=========================================

    printList(head);

    //=========== set everything to head ===========
    current = head;
    prev = head;

    //============= reverses linked list ============
    while(current->next != NULL)
    {   
    next = current->next;   //moves next pointer to next node
    current->prev = next;   //points current's previous to next node
    current = next;         //set current pointer to next node
    current->next = prev;   //set current's next to previous node
    prev = current;         //move prev node up to current
    }
    //================================================

    printList(head);
    cout<<"done";

    return 0;
}    

void printList(node *temp)
{
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<'\n';
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Once I add the reverse function though, it hangs. Actually, the function itself works, but in an IDE, when I LOOP it, it prints out all the values, then just hangs(sits there with blinking cursor) and does nothing.

Solution: Got it to work. This is what my function ended up being.

```
current = head;         //set current pointer to head
prev = head;            //set previous pointer to head


next = current->next;   //moves next pointer to next node
current->next = NULL;   //set the next of the header to NULL, because it will actually be the last
                        //node of reversed list.
current->prev = next;   //set previous of the header to the next node.

while(next != NULL)
{
current = next;
next = current->next;
current->prev = next;
current->next = prev;
prev = current;
}
```

Comment: Have you inserted print statements at each interesting point in the code and traced what happens?   Since you are using an IDE, have you stepped through the code and determined where in the code it is that the IDE "just hangs".   What does "just hangs" mean anyhow?

Comment: I went ahead and added a print statement into the reverse function. This is what I got. Any ideas?

http://ideone.com/nvDNK2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reverse algorithm is basically broken.

On the first pass through:

```
current = head; //  Current is pointing at node 0, node0->next is 1 from before
prev = head; // Prev is pointing at node 0

next = current->next; //  next is pointing at 1
current->prev = next; //  node0->prev is pointing at 1
current = next;       //  current is pointing at 1
current->next = prev  //  node1->next is pointing at 0
```

then next pass

```
next = current->next //  read up there ^^^   node1->next is pointing at 0
```

... so next goes back to to node 0.

That is not what you meant to do - it causes you to loop around nodes 1 and zero repeatedly, instead of progressing to node 2 and beyond...

Note that you could have easily debugged this if you put this code into the reverse loop:

```
cout<<"\nStarting iteration"
cout<<"\nNext is at" << next->data
cout<<"\nCurrent is at" << current->data
cout<<"\nCurrent->next is" << current->next->data
```

etc... doesn't take long to type, reveals all :)

(probably you would cut it down to do 3 instead of 100)

I just did the steps for 3 nodes manually (on paper) to deduce this answer...

Comment: BTW, your creation algorithm leaves the last node with uninitialised data.   That is probably going to cause pain later ;)

Comment: Well, if current is at node 1. Wouldn't `next=current->next` move next to node 2?

Comment: It depends what node1's "next" is pointing to.   As I said, you set node 1's "next" to point to node 0.  So when current is pointing at 1 and node 1's next is pointing at zero ... next=current->next takes you to node zero.

Comment: I editted my answer to try to make it clearer.   If it still isn't clear, the solution is to put a print statement after each line of code, and make it a good descriptive print statement so you can follow the trace easily...

Comment: Awesome. I understand where the mistake is. Will report back when I get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Look this simple solution..

```
Node* Reverse(Node* head)
{
Node * curr=head;
Node * prev=NULL,* nxt=NULL;

while(curr!=NULL)
    {
    nxt=curr->next;

    curr->next=prev;
    curr->prev=nxt;

    prev=curr;
    curr=nxt;
    }

return prev;
// Complete this function
// Do not write the main method. 
}
```